DNS for WireGuard in Docker to create internal connection to traefik
Currently, I have three Docker containers on my VPS (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS): wg-easy (WireGuard VPN), traefik (v3), and whoami (traefik). traefik is set up completely fine and whoami can the reached at test.my-domain.com (Ports 80/443). Also, I can connect to my VPN on Port 51820.
All containers share the same bridge network (172.16.0.0/24). My IP inside the VPN is 10.8.0.2, so I assume that the Network will be 10.8.0.0/24. The ports on 10.8.0.1 can not be used normally as I would with the public IP of my server.
However, I only want to connect to traefik via my VPN and later close ports 80 and 443 in ufw. To achieve that, I tried installing dnsmasq and later pihole in Docker and entered 10.8.0.1 as my DNS server in the VPN configuration. I reversed these changes because the domain did not resolve to my local IP in my VPN or at least, I couldn't get a connection on test.my-domain.com.
Unfortunately, I no longer have any documentation of my procedure. Was the approach with the DNS server correct in theory or is there another way to solve the problem? I would prefer a solution inside docker.

No, DNS is not aware of ports, and won't change what gets routed over the vpn. To limit VPN traffic to port 80/443, you'll need something closer to firewall rules

@Cpt.Whale I don't think I expressed myself correctly. The ports always remain the same. I just want to access traefik via the VPN with e.g. test.my-domain.com. I am currently unable to access the containers from my VPN network, regardless of whether it is via your IP or a domain.
